# The selenium not able to pass data to firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, xpath

i am using selenium 2.39 and firefox 26 for some automation testing using java but i am experiencing some issue, the code inside my java script did run and print out the necessary value inside eclipse but the web browser isn't refreshing.

am i missing out any step or something?

```
driver.manage().timeouts()
    .implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebarId']/li[5]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='treeViewId']/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]/a")).click();

System.out.println("File Electronic Record");
```

the system did print out "File Electronic Record" inside eclipse but the web browser did not click on the xpath above. (p.s there wasn't any error with the xpath) what could the error be?

Comment: it's very vague to help...but i see u are clicking on Links. Try to use  By.ByLinkText("linkText") and check once :)

Comment: i have tried out the way you stated, it isnt working either.

i have another part which is to login using automation,

        driver.findElement(By.name("userId")).sendKeys(List1.get(u));
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='idSubmitBtn']")).click();

the login function return no problem. i think is the firefox fails to refresh the page. are there still any solution to it?